# How to bind together Intl.DateTimeFormat and vueI18n

Tags: vue-i18n, intl

I'm using vueI18n for my translations, but, since I'm doing also some date range formatting, I'm using [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) for building up the dates. The question is: how can I configure Intl in way to get the same locale that is used from vueI18n? So far I'm trying to do:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(i18n.global.locale, options)
```

but if vueI18n is using the fallback, Intl would not use it.

My locales are: `en-US`, `it-IT`

Comment: can you try to provide some visible value of `i18n.global.locale`? eg `ja`, `ja_JP`, ja-JP`

Comment: I added some examples

Comment: `computed(() => new Intl.DateTimeFormat(i18n.global.locale).format(...))` will this work